# Converting a lambda expression to a function to understand it better

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, lambda

I have been trying to decipher a couple of lambda examples in order to fully understand the way that they work and what it means to evaluate 'names'.

I have been sifting through multiple questions of the same nature and all are explained very well, however, I still can't grasp the way that these particular lambda's work. Because of this, I have been trying to write separate functions, mirroring the lambda expressions, and I feel as if this will help me understand them better.

For the following example:

```
funcs = [lambda: i for i in range(3)]
for f in funcs: print(f())
```

This prints the number '2', three times. Why is this? I've been trying to create a function to mirror the exact process that takes place. However, I've been trying multiple methods and still cannot print the number '2', inside my list three times.

However, with the next example, I'm able to understand it a lot better after creating a similar function for it.

```
funcs = [lambda i=i:i for i in range(3)]
for f in funcs: print(f())
```

This prints out 1, 2, 3 respectively, and that's the way I'd like it to work. Here's my custom function:

```
func = []
def i(i):
    for i in range(i):
            func = i

>>> i(3)
0
1
2
```

Is the above function correct in that it mirrors the lambda expression in a way we can detail each step as it is? I've tried my best.

As I've mentioned above, I'm stuck on developing a function in order to mirror that first lambda expression, therefore I don't exactly know how the expression works. Could anyone help me break down how this lambda works; I've been stuck for a while trying to understand how and why names in function bodies are evaluated when the function is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is the equivalent to this:

```
In [ ]:
def outer():
    return x

funcs = []
for x in range(3):
    funcs.append(outer)

for f in funcs:
    print(f())

Out[ ]:
2
2
2
```

But this is just equivalent to:

```
In [ ]:
funcs = [outer] * 3
x = 2
for f in funcs:
    print(f())

Out[ ]:
2
2
2
```

Your second example is equivalent to:

```
In [ ]:
def outer(x):
    def inner():
        return x
    return inner

funcs = []
for x in range(3):
    funcs.append(outer(x))

for f in funcs:
    print(f())

Out[ ]:
0
1
2
```

Much like the closure of `x` in the `inner` function the `lambda i=i: i` forces the lambda to lock in the current value of `i`, whereas `lambda: i` doesn't and it just uses the value of `i` when the lambda gets executed.

Comment: This answer is great. However, I'm still stuck with the first example you've provided. I've been trying for hours on end to understand what exactly is going on. When I run the loop once, `0` gets appended to `funcs`. How come when the loop runs a second time, it overwrites the `0` already appended to `funcs` and replaces it with `1`, and appends another `1`? When I run the loop a third time (range(3)), `2` overwrites the current values in the list, and appends a `2` to it...

What is the logic that's going on behind all this? It's got me totally stumped.

Comment: In the first example, `outer` is not being executed, so `0` is not being appended to `funcs`, just a function that returns `x` is appended, the same for the 2nd and 3rd iteration. When then function is executed after the loop `x` is `2`, so each function just returns `2`.

Comment: Wow that makes perfect sense. I thought we were appending our iterator value into the list...

Thank you so much for helping me understand my problem a lot deeper.